# Missing reputation tab on meta.unix.stackexchange.com account page

Tags: bug, reputation

I seem to be missing the `reputation` tab on my http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com account page, and options to view specific information about this subject through dropdown that is displayed by click my username.

I have both of these on (for example) http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

I am actually not also sure if there was ever one on http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com

Can provide screenshots if any of the above is confusing, but hope someone knows why straight away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per-site metas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) don't have their own reputation, they inherit reputation from the parent site, so there's no need for a reputation tab on the profile page. The meta sites for the original three sites were created before we had per-site metas (which were created for SE 2.0 sites). The SU and SF metas were converted, but Meta Stack Overflow is unusually large and acts as the meta site for the whole network, so it was left like a regular site with its own accounts and reputation

Comment: Didn't realise this... Thanks for the link. However, I notice that I have a different reputation on http://meta.unix.stackoverflow.com, than I have on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (Latter is far larger). I can sort of understand the thinking that a reputation tab on the profile page of per-site meta's is not needed (Though I don't agree... Would save some clicks), but only if the reputation is shared, which it appears it isn't.

Comment: @user66001 You share per-site meta reputation with the corresponding parent site. E.g. here, your [main Unix and Linux account](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18377/user66001) shares rep with your [meta Unix and Linux account](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/users/18377/user66001), so that you get privileges on a site's meta just by participating on the main site. If you go on meta Super User, you'll have the same rep you have on main Super User, etc.

Comment: Oh, that parent :) So guess my comments about saving clicks, by having both meta and sub-site parent with links to the same rep page, is all that is left.